# WPF Performance - Finding Source of Layout Pass Invocation

Tags: wpf, performance, wpf-controls

Is there any way to figure out why/what invoked the WPF layout pass for a control?

I am currently tracking amount of Arrange Overrides that are being called for our main user control:

```
public partial class MyView
{
    private ulong _arrangeCount;
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"TTV - ArrangeOverride - {_arrangeCount++}");
        return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
    }
}
```

The counts of just loading the view are 40! With a complex UI (data grids nested, with 100's of cells and custom templates for columns,cells,rows) this is taking seconds! (a large portion of the time is spent in Measure/Arrange)

Is there any way to find out the source of each pass?

At the moment I am removing things from my user control and trying to figure out what is causing a bunch of these.

I did notice there is a lot of things stored in effective values, could that be because of bindings in styles/templates inside the main control resource dictionaries?

Would an update to those effective values (even though some of them do not affect this parent control, cause Measure/Arrange to get invoked?)

I have managed to cache the Measure size as follows which seems to have helped on the measure side, but for arrange, I cannot do the same as it does not arrange correctly, after content has been bound!

```
    private Size _lastMeasureConstraint;

    private ulong _measureCount;
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        if (_lastMeasureConstraint == constraint)
            return constraint;

        Debug.WriteLine($"TTV - MeasureOverride - {_measureCount++}");
        _lastMeasureConstraint = constraint;
        return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
    }
```

Stack of most of the measure/arrange overrides:

```
 at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()

   // This is where I hook in to check how many arrange overrides happen
   at MyAssembly.MyUserControl.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds) in MyUserControl.cs:line 103
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)

   // This is what makes me think that this is an animation? I could be wrong though!
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.AnimatedRenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherOperation operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback, DispatcherPriority priority, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback, DispatcherPriority priority)

   // Dispatcher Wrapper that exposes async/await methods. This is the await state machine
   at MyAssembly.Services.Dispatcher.WpfDispatcher.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext() in WpfDispatcher.cs:line 37
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at MyAssembly.Services.Dispatcher.WpfDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Action action)
   at MyAssembly.Services.Dispatcher.Dispatch.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Action action) in Dispatch.cs:line 176
   at MyAssembly.Services.Dispatcher.Dispatch.P3_ContextIdle(Action action) in Dispatch.cs:line 76

   // This is the top level await, where the async/await state machine starts
   at MyAssembly.MyUserControl.<>c__DisplayClass348_0.<<MyMethod>b__0>d.MoveNext() in MyUserControl.cs:line 3449
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at  MyAssembly.App.Main()
```

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` contributes a lot to those changes. So if you add items to your collections or change property on your `ViewModel` it triggers the UI update. I am not sure how often this happens but for each notification I sometimes had control updated twice.

Comment: @XAMlMAX thanks for the suggestion, checked, and there may be half a dozen due to prop changes, but I can see after setting last prop change there is still another 20 measure overrides. Stack trace is pointing to animation, but nothing is being animated, at least in our code!

Comment: In your post you state that you have nested `DataGrid`s, are you using virtualisation? That would ease the amount of generated UI items, also if your `DataTemplate`s are using `UserControl`s that will also, heavily, impact the performance. There are many factors that would contribute to your problem.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Yes, Row virtualization is on (vertical), unfortunately horizontal virtualization as it becomes to slow to scroll horizontal otherwise. We are using DevExpress grid, so don't have too much of an option there... but I know that the tree is way too big! Have been trying to make it as small as possible, without completely re-skinning/re-doing the grid.